# Adding promise polyfill to ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, ecmascript-6

I have a React project written in ES6. It is compiled using Babel and works quite well. Except for one promise (of many!) that acts up only in IE, for which I already know - has no support for promises. So I immediately thought to add a polyfill to supply promises for IE, but then I was like "Hold up, you're already writing ES6 and isn't that compiled into ES5 anyways?" Who would know better than SO?
So is there any sense in adding a polyfill such as [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) to my project? And if there is, how should I use it syntactically? For now I only have the import but I should probably implement it somehow as well?

```
import Promise from 'es6-promise';
```

Also here's the promise that causes problems in IE, perhaps I have a syntax error that I haven't noticed myself! :)

```
new SingleObjectResource(DJ_CONST.API.setLanguage)
    .put(null, {language_code: theLanguage})
    .then(
        function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Babel only transpiles the language features to ES5. You still need [polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) :) Just drop that at the top of your pages, don't worry about `import`ing anything, just write the ES6 like it was natively available

Comment: es6-promise is a slow and pretty outdated polyfill afaik.

Comment: RGraham, I'll try it out first chance I get but it already seems that you managed to capture the answer I expected in just two sentences. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) everywhere? Its [faster than the native promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark). And [polyfills for IE](https://github.com/este/este/issues/599) too. And I don't work for them :).

Comment: Is `SingleObjectResource` something you made, or a 3rd party library? Are you getting some kind of error in the console? If not, try adding a `.catch(function (error) { console.log(error); })` after your `.then()`.

Comment: `SingleObjectResource` is part of a library. Now that I added babel-polyfill to my project, IE is still not functioning and I am receiving an `unhandled promise rejection error` in IE console. Dunno if it was there before adding babel though. It only appeared after some waiting, not right away. Anyhows - should I import the polyfill in the file that contains the `SingleObjectResource` or in the file that calls the function that contains the `SingleObjectResource`?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same situation & was very frustrated as i had to deploy production app, The problem i had was with Promises from fetchjs. This is what i do to save my life

```
npm install --save es6-promise //first install as a dependency & then added in broswerify as dependency.
```

and then in my main JS file, justed called this

```
   import "es6-promise/auto";
```

as from here https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise#auto-polyfill

basically, its alternative syntax of

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

Basically, Under the hood **The polyfill() method will patch the global environment** (in this case to the Promise name) when called.

**Note**: i was using gulp with browserify.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't edit my previous response earlier as I received the review comment in the night when I was offline... re-posting my response with embedded information per the review feedback. Thanks.

Why not use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) everywhere? Its [faster than the native promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark). And [polyfills for IE](https://github.com/este/este/issues/599) too. And I don't work for them :).

**EDIT:**

Using bluebird instead of native promise -

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
```

### 1. Added perf comparisons -

```
results for 10000 parallel executions, 1 ms per I/O op

file                                     time(ms)  memory(MB)
callbacks-baseline.js                         232       35.86
promises-bluebird-generator.js                235       38.04
promises-bluebird.js                          335       52.08
promises-cujojs-when.js                       405       75.77
promises-tildeio-rsvp.js                      468       87.56
promises-dfilatov-vow.js                      578      125.98
callbacks-caolan-async-waterfall.js           634       88.64
promises-lvivski-davy.js                      653      109.64
promises-calvinmetcalf-lie.js                 732      165.41
promises-obvious-kew.js                      1346      261.69
promises-ecmascript6-native.js               1348      189.29
generators-tj-co.js                          1419      164.03
promises-then-promise.js                     1571      294.45
promises-medikoo-deferred.js                 2091      262.18
observables-Reactive-Extensions-RxJS.js      3201      356.76
observables-caolan-highland.js               7429      616.78
promises-kriskowal-q.js                      9952      694.23
observables-baconjs-bacon.js.js             25805      885.55

Platform info:
Windows_NT 6.1.7601 x64
Node.JS 1.1.0
V8 4.1.0.14
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4
```

**2. IE Polyfill code -**

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
// Node
global.Promise = Bluebird;
// Browser
window.Promise = Bluebird;
```

Comment: This *still* doesn't answer the question, you're answering "how do I select an element" with "use jQuery". The performance benchmark is completely irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Your comparison is understandable but I disagree that my comment is irrelevant on the topic at hand. The OP has presented a possible cross-browser issue on IE with Promise and is also evaluating using another polyfill which is proven to be slower than bluebird. The alternative I mentioned is not only faster than the natives, it supports IE as well. An argument similar to your example would be... use jQuery instead of say querySelector because the latter is not supported yet by all browsers.

Comment: The issue of performance is irrelevant to this question, the issue of browser compatibility is.

Comment: It appears to be relevant, as Benjamin mentioned, the es6 polyfill is slow which is an important factor. The OP has explicitly asked for recommendations on using it. Anyways, I'd let the OP decide.

Comment: Speed definitely makes for a valid point, however if I succeed with babel, I would prefer a solution that doesn't include another library (since I'm already running babel). Of course if I was running `es6-promise` as I was planning in the beginning, then your post would have much more relevance since `es6-promise` is a separate library as well.  But your initial post definitely failed to deliver how to exactly implement bluebird, it just pointed out that it would make good replacement for `es6-promise` - that remark would have better fit in a comment I think.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that how to use bluebird needs explanation. Mostly it is - 

`const Promise = require('bluebird');`

Answer (score 1):

Although you are using Babel (just traspiling and not adding functionality), polyfills are needed.

All you have to do is installing the package:

```
npm install --save es6-promise
```

Inside `webpack.config.js` (or wherever your webpack configurations are, assuming you are using webpack)

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

The polyfill() method will patch the global environment (in this case to the Promise name) when called. More info at https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: How do you write "require('es6-promise').polyfill();" as an es6 import statement ?

Comment: You can try using the `import` notation. I also have an ES6 project, but I still write this line as ES5.